# How to calculate hash-max-ziplist-value properly?

Tags: redis

My question example: `HMSET myhash field1 value1 field2 value2` and myhash only has these two fields.

The main question is how to calculate `hash-max-ziplist-value` so that my hash will not exceed the value to maintain my hash in a compressed format to minimize the memory usage.

Thank "Kevin Christopher Henry" very much for his detail explanation, help and time. Due to my limited English, I will summarize Kevin's answer here. Please correct me if what I understand is wrong.

(1) To meet `hash-max-ziplist-value`, I need to calculate max(`field1`, `value1`, `field2`, `value2`). Let's assume `value1` has the biggest size. Then I just need to make sure the size of `value1` does not exceed `hash-max-ziplist-value`.

(2) To calculate `value1`, I just need to calculate the number of bytes in size. Because `hash-max-ziplist-value` is the number of bytes for the string value before any compression.

(3) To calculate the number of bytes for `value1`, there are many ways and one of them is as follows: First, convert `value1` to UTF8 encoding if it's not. Second, check the length of it by using the client language. Because The length of UTF8 encoded string is the number of bytes in Size. (for instance: `utf8.encode(value1).length`).

### Originl Post

For example, `HMSET myhash field1 value1 field2 value2`

- First, I want to clarify what `hash-max-ziplist-entries` really means.

Is the above example one entry or two entries because it has two fields?

- What is `hash-max-ziplist-value`? Is that the size in bytes for

(a) `MEMORY USAGE myhash`

(b) the sum size of `field1`, `value1`, `field2`, `value2`

(c) the sum size of `value1` and `value2`.

(d) max(`value1`, `value2`)?

(e) max(`field1`+`value1`, `field2`+`value2`)

- I don't know how I can calculate my hash value to match `hash-max-ziplist-value`. Is `hash-max-ziplist-value` the number of bytes in size? Is that utf-8 encoded string length? Is there an existing command in redis for this calculation?.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These values are briefly described in the [`redis.conf`](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf) file, as well as the [memory optimization documentation](https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization).

> # Hashes are encoded using a memory efficient data structure when they have a
>   # small number of entries, and the biggest entry does not exceed a given
>   # threshold. These thresholds can be configured using the following directives.
>   hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
>   hash-max-ziplist-value 64

Using these default values as an example, if the hash has 512 or fewer entries, and each is 64 bytes or smaller, the hash will be encoded using a ziplist.

Although the documentation doesn't say exactly how the size of a hash entry is calculated, a look at [the source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/de035c94816722dd923e4aedd852869de79a5185/src/t_hash.c) indicates that both the field name and the value must have a size less than or equal to the threshold. You should be able to determine the size by computing the length, in bytes, of the binary string.

To answer some of your specific questions:

> Is the above example one entry or two entries because it has two fields?

Two.

> What is `hash-max-ziplist-value`?

Using your terminology, this would be `max(field1, value1, field2, value2)`.

> Is that utf-8 encoded string calculation?

Redis works with binary strings. It's up to you (or your client) to decide what encoding to use.

> Is there any easy way to calculate myhash value in bytes for `hash-max-ziplist-value`? Is there an existing command in redis for this calculation?

Not that I know of, but the length of the binary string representation of the value should be approximately right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Now, I just don't know how to calculate the size of value1 or value2. You said that would be a binary string representation. So how can I calculate that binary string representation in redis? Thanks.

Comment: @sgon00: What do you mean by "in redis"? If your goal is to make sure you meet the requirements for a ziplist, presumably you want to know the size of the value *before* you send it to Redis. How you do that depends on your programming language, client, etc.

Comment: @sgon00: For example, in Python you might use `len("value".encode("utf-8"))`.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to make sure if it meets the requirement. I thought the requirement is the size of a binary string in redis instead of the length of the string. thus (1) Do I just calculate the length of the string? I just read your new comment. It seems that I was wrong. I don't need to calculate the binary string size in redis, instead, I just need to calculate the length.  (2) Do I have to convert it to `utf-8`? I am going to use `go` and `dart`. I think go uses utf-8 and dart uses utf-16. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sgon00: A Redis string is just a series of bytes, so the length of the *binary* string is the same as its size in bytes. Redis doesn't know or care about the encoding; that's up to you. If you (or your client library) will encode strings as `utf-16`, then that's what will determine the size.

Comment: Thanks for your patient. Does it mean I just need to check the length of the string in my client language? and the length will be the value for `hash-max-ziplist-value`? I just checked `len("Hello你")` in golang and it returns `8`. And `"Hello你".length` in dart and it returns `6`. The results are different. But I think when I store `Hello你` in redis, it should use the same size. Thus what is the size of `Hello你`? How to set the value `hash-max-ziplist-value` so that it has the same size of `Hello你`? Should `hash-max-ziplist-value` be 8 or 6 or other value? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sgon00: I added an example to the answer.

Comment: First, thank you very much for your time. Because your answer is talking about multiple clients and if I choose utf-8 encoding, this makes me confused. What if I use one client and choose utf-16 encoding? Can I do that? Does Redis string support utf-16 encoding? If so, will the string value be different? What encoding does `redis-cli set mykey string` use? Can I say all clients use utf-8 encoding strings? If I can choose different encoding, it seems that utf-16 encoding will have less length (less bytes in size) than utf-8 encoding for the string `Hello你` in Redis. Is that true?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194516/discussion-between-kevin-christopher-henry-and-sgon00).